# How do I have points and polygons in the same Leaflet map?

Tags: location, javascript

I have two content types

1. Location that geocodes an addressfield to place markers on the map
2. Boundary that uses a geojson field to create complex shapes on the map

I need to use views to show both content types on the same map. It appears that I can only do one or the other.

For an example, think about a map that shows constituency boundaries and voting stations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nigel Waters has it correct. Here are the details. I did this for cities and states. I used points for cities and polygons for states. Here are the steps.

Requirements:

- Geofield module
- Leaflet module
- Leaflet Views module (a submodule of Leaflet)

Steps:

- Create the two content types: City and State.
- Create a field of type Geofield, call it "Location"
- Choose GeoJSON as the field widget
- Add the Location field to both content types
- Create a city. For location enter [GeoJSON Point](http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html#id2) data
- Create a state. For location enter a [GeoJSON Polygon](http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html#polygon) data
- Create a view with a Page display
- Add the Location field to the view
- Filter the view by State and City content types
- Set the Format of the view to Leaflet Map
- Your view should now look like pic 1
- Click on View Page
- You should see a map like pic 2

[image: View]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

To answer my own question is to use the same field on both content types. I used a geojson (geofield) field which accepts both points and polygons to merge into a single leaflet map in views.

Comment: mmm... it would be very interesting to get a more deep explanation about did you do that... thanks in advance

Comment: I am not going to write out an entire tutorial as I don't have the time. Just add a geofield of type "geojson", then just add your points and polygons using geojson. I found the following site very helpful to draw out what i needed and then I just pasted the json directly into the field of my content type. http://geojson.io/

Comment: No need to write a tutorial. I see your geojson is not dynamic (I need create map based on views) so its not useful for me. Thanks in any case.

Comment: It is dynamic. I use views to place the markers on the map and a proximity search function.

Answer (score 0):

To show multiple content types in the same View:

- Edit your view
- Under "**Filter Criteria**" click "**Content: Type**"
- Select both content types under the "Content types" section
- Click Apply

Comment: Could you add 2 screenshots? One that shows configuration needed, and other that shows both points and polygons actually displayed in the same Leaflet map?

Comment: @Molot It doesn't matter. This doesn't answer the question. The question is not how to add two content types to a view. The question is how to add to content types to a leaflet map. THe leaflet map settings in a view only allow for one field from one content type.

Comment: @NigelWaters if module clearly disallows what you are trying to do, it is a feature request and should be posted in module's issue queue rather than here. Unless you are trying to code a fix - in that case, show the code you are using, or the part of code that is relevant to the question.

Comment: The module does not "clearly" disallow what I am trying to do. The Leaflet API definitely allows this and there are also several Drupal examples of combining these features into one map. I was hoping that one with experience could point me in the right direction.